# Application taking phone_state as idle from the very starting point of application. This is not needed

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

```
private ImageButton malayalam, hindi, tamil;

private MediaPlayer mp = null;
ImageButton pause;
ImageView facebook, twitter, linkedin;
private String TAG = "debug";
boolean playVideo = false, pauseVideo = true, isVideoPlaying = false, streaming = true;
TextView stream, events;
AudioManager audioManager;
ProgressBar progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


    progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    facebook = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facebook);
    twitter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.twitter);
    linkedin = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.linkedin);
    pause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    stream = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    events = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.events);
    playFm();
    ;


    audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
    volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
    volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (playVideo) {

                playVideo = false;
                pauseVideo = true;
                isVideoPlaying = true;
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                onPrepared(mp);
            } else {

                pauseFm();
                playVideo = true;
                pauseVideo = false;
                isVideoPlaying = false;
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MyTuneIndia.this, "paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            }


        }
    });


    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                // do all necessary action to pause the audio
                if (mp != null) {// check mp
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MyTuneIndia.this, "Incoming call..!!.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pauseFm();
                        playVideo = true;
                        pauseVideo = false;
                        isVideoPlaying = false;
                        pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(MyTuneIndia.this, "paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

                    }
                }
                // Incoming call: Pause music
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                Toast.makeText(MyTuneIndia.this, "Playing Again..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                playVideo = false;
                pauseVideo = true;
                isVideoPlaying = true;
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                onPrepared(mp);
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                Toast.makeText(MyTuneIndia.this, "Outgoing Call..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                pauseFm();
                playVideo = true;
                pauseVideo = false;
                isVideoPlaying = false;
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MyTuneIndia.this, "paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };// end PhoneStateListener

    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mgr != null) {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}


public void playFm() {
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://xxx.mp3");
    try {
        if (mp == null) {
            this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
        } else {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        }
        mp.setDataSource(this, myUri); // Go to Initialized state
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

        mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mp.prepareAsync();

        Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
    }

}

public void pauseFm() {

    mp.pause();
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
    pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    stream.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    streaming = false;
    isVideoPlaying = true;
    if (isVideoPlaying)
        mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isVideoPlaying) {
        mp.stop();
        finish();
    } else if (streaming) {
        Toast.makeText(MyTuneIndia.this, "Streaming stopped..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        finish();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is my code for an online audio player which streams audio and plays. Now the problem is that it should run the code when the app is just launched. But it is doing so. When I launch the application from launcher, it will say "playing again" which is not in my main code but this `PHONE_STATE_IDLE` part of the code. So can any one please suggest me what to do so that for the first time app runs as designed and this `PHONE_STATE_IDLE` part of code is implemented only when any call is received or made while app is already running.
Thanx a lot in advance..

Hope u all got wat i meant..

Comment: @andr whats d edited part.?

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your code for others, so that reading it is less painfull. Feel free to roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: no dats very nice of u.. bt please someone help me out with this..